# Parse filename by split() to compare two common fields

Tags: java, parsing, split

I need to extract String parts from each file in a folder(files) having the following extensions as png,jpg,jpeg,PNG,JPG,JPEG. The file naming convention is as below(These are 2 different files but the only thing they have in common is the TIMESTAMP which will be required to get the FILENAME:

AIRLINECODE_PARTNERCODE_INVOICENO_timestamp.FILETYPE

FILENAME.FILETYPE_timestamp

Example file names:

ET_PRH_4_**20170309140404**.png

gosalyn.png_**20170309140404**

After reading the field from the first, I need to write each of the capital fields to the database (for eg AIRLINECODE, PARTNERCODE to columns in db). I am looping to iterate through "eachFile" in "files". The capital words are depicting the fields which will be added to the columns in the database. So AIRLINE_CODE has a column in the db and ET will be placed in it and so on for the others.

The following is the code I have written so far, so could you kindly guide how I can compare the second file's timestamp with the first and storing it in a field called "timestamp". Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Pathnames {
    
    public void readFilename() {
        // try-catch block to handle exceptions
        try {
            File f = new File("C:\\Users\\rsaeed\\Desktop\\files");

            FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File f, String name) {
                    return name.endsWith(".png") || name.endsWith(".PNG") || name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".JPG") || name.endsWith(".jpeg") || name.endsWith(".JPEG");
                }
            };

            // using a File class as an array
            File[] files = f.listFiles(filter);
            if(files != null) {
                for(File eachFile : files) {
                    String[] partsOfName = eachFile.getName().split("_|\\."); // this part is correct and giving result in array as [ET, PRH, 4, 20170309140404, png]
                    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(partsOfName));

                    // the following is wrong so what should be the code here that each file with .png_ is split and timestamp stored in secondFile array after which I can compare the two timestamps
                    if(eachFile.getName().contains(".png_")) {
                        String[] secondFile = eachFile.getName().split("\\_");
                        
                        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secondFile));
                    }
                    
                    final String timestamp = partsOfName[3];
                    //System.out.println(timestamp);
                }
            }

            
            // Get the names of the files by using the .getName() method
            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(files[i].getName());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        Pathnames p = new Pathnames();
        p.readFilename();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will first share with you a little hint

```
@Override
                public boolean accept(File f, String name) {
                    // Here you can leave the toLowerCase() to easy your life for sake of comparison since PNG and png is the same for you (this doesn't change the original name)
                    name = name.toLowerCase();
                    return name.endsWith(".png") || name.endsWith(".jpg") || name.endsWith(".jpeg");
                }
```

To finally split your secondFile (i'm guessing for what you write this was your difficulty)
I made a simply regex to split as you requested:

So gosalyn.png_20170309140404 will be stored as [gosalyn, png, 20170309140404]

This regex will solve your problem "\.|\_"

1. '\.' is for any '.'
2. '|' is just like || (or)
3. '\_' is for any '_'